# Can I request IdentityServer4 tokens from client if server was rebooted?

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, identityserver4

Its very difficult to ask questions on ID4. Also all relevant discussions I could google point to non-existing links for code samples.

What I have: an angular client uses ID4 auth made up of MVC pages provided by Microsoft, hosted in ASP.NET Core.

Startup.cs

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>();

services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, AppDbContext>();

services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddIdentityServerJwt();

. . .

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseIdentityServer();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

authorize.service.ts

```
const settings: any = await response.json();
settings.automaticSilentRenew = true;
settings.includeIdTokenInSilentRenew = true;
this.userManager = new UserManager(settings);
```

Use case: a user logs in on the webpage, ticks Remeber Me checkbox and uses the auth'ed website parts. If the server restarts - the tokens lost and user interaction with the website becomes broken - e.g. there are no errors in the webbrowser console and nothing happens if user tries to access any server-side data. It looks like nothing is there. Not as if there is issue with the auth.

It can only be fixed by manually logout/login. Or by opening new tab and going to the app again.

**Is there simple explanation on to how can I a) detect that client token is broken and b) request new token?**

**EDIT** if a user continues to use website next working day or opens new browser tab (without server restart) the ID4 works as expected - no login required.

The fiddler:

[image]

Comment: What is _the server_?
What does _tokens are lost_ mean? (I believe you usually put them into local storage.)
Are you using refresh tokens?
Even if from Angular you start another login flow then IdentityServer should redirect straight back because its cookies are still in the browser from last time the user logged in -- unless they've expired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is: nothing should break if the server process (either application backend or `identityserver4`-based IDP) restarts so chances are you're missing some persistence (for persisted grants) and/or shared config (e.g. token signing keys and ASP.Net data protection keys) and things are being regenerated on startup and in-memory data is being lost.

This article covers the things you need to consider to deploy a viable production service: https://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/deployment.html

With that all in place though tokens will still expire and there are a couple of ways to refresh them depending on the context and grant type in use.

To detect if a token is not valid anymore:

1. Use it and detect if you get a 401 response from the endpoint you're calling
2. Check the `exp` claim inside the token yourself
3. Use the `expires_in` value returned with the token and calculate the expiry time based on that

To renew it (and some libs will automate this):

1. Use the iframe-based silent renewal mechanism (authorize endpoint with prompt=none) - note that third part cookie restrictions come into play for this
2. Use a refresh token via the token endpoint (not recommended for client side apps due to the need to persist a refresh token in the client side)

Comment: I know it is lame but its best I can do - why cant it work the same way as it works when a user opens website next day? in that case ID4 somehow manage to log them in silently. I dont really want to do persistent storage. I feel it will drag me into abyss of unknown. **PS I have records in the PersistentGrants table - does it help?**

Comment: RE: renew token. The client set to use it already `automaticSilentRenew = true`.

Comment: You'll have to at least make sure your security keys are not transient otherwise stuff will break everytime the service is restarted and it won't work at all if you have more than one instance service traffic.

Comment: As for your first comment - how is it working in that situation? Is it doing a top level redirect to the authorize endpoint?

Comment: see the edit please - it goes to `/connect/authorize`